404 NOT_FOUND When deploying vercel backend application
vercel.jsonI want to deploy my backend node project on vercel , This is my first time using vercel and I installed vercel@latest after installing it I created a vercel.json file which mentions the version, builds and routes for vercel deployment.
Am I missing something?
The structure for my app is that I have a main folder which has client and server side and I want to deploy the server side
The vercel.json file is present in server folder and the starting point is server.js
I was expecting for vercel to work properly but instead it shows 404 NOT _FOUND when depolyed
